# C++ how to std::accumulate vector of futures?

Tags: c++, concurrency, future

Why following code does not compile?

```
#include <future>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    const std::vector<int> values{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    auto futures = std::accumulate(
        begin(values), end(values), std::vector<std::future<int>>{},
        [](auto accumulator, auto value) {
            accumulator.push_back(
                async(std::launch::async, [value] { return value; }));
            return accumulator;
        });
}
```

https://cpp.godbolt.org/z/c967ra1hY

Interestingly enough, using implementation of accumulate from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate#Version_2) works https://cpp.godbolt.org/z/MdM8Wh3Eq.

Comment: you can switch compilers in godbolt but still have errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a defect in the specification of `std::accumulate`. The algorithm was specified to repeatedly copy the accumulator into the `binary_op` argument. This was [changed](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0616r0.pdf) to repeated moves in C++20. Therefore the standard library implementations exhihit different behaviour in C++20 compared to older standards, as you can see [here](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/main/stl/inc/numeric) (from line 31) in the example of MSVC.

That is what breaks your code prior to C++20, because a `std::vector` of `std::future`'s is not copyable. So add the compiler switch `/std:c++20`. If you're stuck with an older standard, you're probably out of luck, even if it isn't really your fault.

Comment: Your answer is correct and clear, thank you.

Comment: Thank you. However the question remains, why cppreference says that the move is happening in C++11 and later.

Comment: @chrysante Cppreference applies defect reports transparently to the description. So if the defect report is intended to apply to all versions since C++11 they will just write it as if it was always specified that way since C++11. They list the defect reports at the end of the article. MS STL may have decided to not apply to previous standard modes regardless.

Comment: Thank you @user17732522. Apparently libc++ and libstdc++ have decided the same. Any idea why? It should not be an ABI compatibility issue as far as I can tell.

Comment: @chrysante I don't know. I also don't know whether it says anywhere "officially" that the change is considered a DR and against what standard revisions. But normally cppreference seems quite trustworthy on that. (For newer changes that's normally stated with voting results at https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues, but this change is too old.) (And to be clear, I don't know either whether it is really considered a DR other than from what is stated at cppreference.)